# How to upload a project to GitHub

Tags: upload, github, repository, git-bash, git-gui

After checking *[How can I upload my project's Git repository to GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6674752/5740428)*, I still have no idea how to get a project uploaded to my GitHub repository.

I created a repository and want to upload my project to it.

I've looked on the repository page for an upload button of some kind, but I haven't seen anything of the sort.

I've looked at the links provided so far, but I'm still getting nowhere. They mention command line; is that Windows command line or [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway)? Because I can't get either to do anything.

I also tried using the Git GUI, but when I select the folder I want it says that it's not a Git repository...does it need to be zipped up? I tried adding the `.gitconfig` file in the folder, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) implies [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows). Is that a necessary restriction or not?

Answer (score 407, accepted):

GitHub released a native [Windows client](http://windows.github.com/) which makes all the below steps redundant.

You can also use [Sourcetree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/download/) to get both Git and [Mercurial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) setup on Windows.

---

Here is how you would do it in Windows:

1. If you don't have Git installed, see [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) on how to set it up.
2. Open up a Windows command prompt.
3. Change into the directory where your source code is located in the command prompt.
4. First, create a new repository in this directory `git init`. This will say *"Initialized empty git repository in ....git"* (`...` is the path).
5. Now you need to tell Git about your files by adding them to your repository. Do this with `git add filename`. If you want to add all your files, you can do `git add .`
6. Now that you have added your files and made your changes, you need to *commit* your changes so Git can track them. Type `git commit -m "adding files"`. `-m` lets you add the *commit message* in line.

So far, the above steps is what you would do even if you were not using GitHub. They are the normal steps to start a Git repository.  Remember that Git is distributed (decentralized), meaning you don't need to have a "central server" (or even a network connection), to use Git.

Now you want to push the changes to your Git repository hosted with GitHub. You do this by telling Git to *add a remote location*, and you do that with this command:

`git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/your-repo-name.git`

*Note: `your-repo-name` should be created in GitHub before you do a `git remote add origin ...`

Once you have done that, Git now knows about your remote repository. You can then tell it to push (which is "upload") your committed files:

`git push -u origin master`

Comment: I followed this in windows command prompt and it said that git was not recognised basically. But I followed it in Git Bash and it got all the way to the end and after asking for my username and password it said error: src ref spec master does not match any. error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/jampez77/TV43.git'

Comment: After a bit of research i figured it out. If i use git pull origin master before push it works perfectly....thanks :)

Comment: could not understand 2nd point. If u change directory to where source file r located, then how can u access git commands from thr?

Comment: What if we don't already have Git installed? Where can we find it?

Comment: After following the same step getting this error, don't know why ? any help. error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/RishikeshPathak/mavenApp'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first merge the remote changes (e.g.,
hint: 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: The clue is right there in the error message: _"Updates were rejected because **the remote contains work that you do not have locally.** You may want to first merge the remote changes (e.g., 'git pull') before pushing again."_ - this means there is already a repository setup, so you need to clone it first, then push your changes. This question is for when you are setting up a brand new repository.

Comment: Thanks Burhan, is there a way to this through the web? I am using the computer in the office that others use and rather not download software to the computer

Comment: @Tomer, I suppose you could use one of those "ide on the cloud" providers, but it would be a lot simpler to use the [portable version](https://git-scm.com/download/win) of git (for Windows), which has no installation requirements.

Comment: I think step 1 of this process should be "Go to your account on github and create the repository that you want to push files to if you haven't already."  The OP did mention s/he had done that, but I doubt I'm the only one who skipped right to the accepted solution and therefore missed the step in the OP's question. I thought the push process might create the repository, so I kept getting "Repository not found" until it dawned on me.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid could you please also add in your answer that you should avoid adding /vs folder while adding git files (don't need to explain the why here, maybe can just give a link/tell to self search). The thing is I think a lot of newbies like me finds your answer perfectly helpful but adding the /vs folder creates a lot of problems afterwards which ofc most people won't know in the first place. Your edit would be highly appreciated. And thanks for this answer : )

Comment: @BeginnerTejas you may want to look at creating a [`gitignore` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), which will exclude folders from git. You can use [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/) to help generate a gitignore file.

Answer (score 110):

[image: How to upload a project to GitHub from scratch]

Follow these steps to upload a project to GitHub:

1. `git init`
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m "Add all my files"`
4. `git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/your-repo-name.git`

   > Upload of project from scratch require `git pull origin master`.
5. `git pull origin master`
6. `git push origin master`

Comment: The problem with github is that you have to do this weird step.  Bonus points in the answer if you would replace the image with text for copy/paste.

Comment: I get to "git pull origin master" then get an error "fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories"

Comment: Why the need to do git pull before git push?

Comment: Oh no, not again. See: *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)*. It includes (my emphasis) *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way***, *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*

Comment: Something is missing in *"Follow these steps to project to GitHub"*.

Answer (score 39):

```
git push --force origin master
```

if you have problems uploading!

Comment: Logged in only to upvote this awesome answer ! All i was missing for Christmas is `--force`

Comment: But risking ruining something?

Answer (score 23):

Here I explain how I did it on Windows.

Make sure to install [Git](https://git-scm.com/) and [GitHub](https://desktop.github.com/).

After installation is complete, open [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway).

[image]

So a window like below is going to pop up:

[image]

Go ahead and type `cd ~` to make sure you are in the home directory. You can check the address that you are in it by typing `pwd`;

Now you need to create a [GitHub](https://github.com/) account. After creating a GitHub account, go ahead and sign in.

After you signed in, on the top right click on the <kbd>+</kbd> and choose “New Repository”

[image]

Then in the opened window, type the name that you wish to have for the repository in the “Repository name” box. Add “Description (optional)” if you like, and mark “Initialize this repository with a README”. Then click on “Create repository”.

[image]

Now go to your C drive; create a new folder and name it “git”. Now go to the “Git Bash” window; change the directory to c drive by typing `cd ~; cd /c`.
If you type `ls` there it would show you the folders there. Make sure it shows the Git folder there:

[image]

Now go back to the browser; go to your GitHub page, click on the repository that you made, click on “Clone or download”, and copy the address that shows there (by choosing copy to clipboard).

[image]

Now going back to “Git Bash”. Use the command `cd git` to go to the git folder; now write the following commands to connect to your GitHub (enter the username and password of your GitHub when it asks you):

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

And then: `git config --global user.email youremail@domain.com`.

Next type: `git clone (URL)`, instead of the (URL), type the address of the GitHub repository that you copied from your GitHub page; (e.g., `git clone https://github.com/isalirezag/Test.git`).

Now if you do `ls` command you will see your repository there. If you also open the Git folder that you have in your window you will see that your repository is added as a folder.

Now use the *cd* command to go to the repository: `cd Test`

Go ahead and copy and paste any files that you want to put in this repository in that folder.

In order to transfer the files to your repository you need to do following now:

Type `git`

`add filename` (filename is the file name that you want to upload) or you can type the command below if you want to add all the files in the folder:

`git add .`

Then type: `git commit -m "adding files"`. And then: `git push -u origin master` .

And then you should be all set. If you refresh your GitHub account, the files should be there :)

Answer (score 22):

Follow these steps to upload your project to GitHub:

1. `git init`
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m "Add all my files"`
4. `git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/your-repo-name.git`

Upload of the project from scratch requires `git pull origin master`.

5. `git pull origin master`
6. `git push origin master`

If any problem occurs in pushing, use `git push --force origin master`.

Comment: You straight away copied answer of @RishiKesh Pathak.

Comment: `git push --force origin master` solved my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Follow these two steps:

1. Create the repository online using the link: https://github.com/new
2. Then link your local repo to the remote repo using the command: `git add remote origin https://github.com/userName/repo.git`
   Here the repo.git will be your newly created remote repo.

This will work like a charm. No need to worry about the SSH or HTTPS ways. I first faced the same issue and spent hours for solution. 
But this worked for me.

Comment: Does this still work like a charm?

Answer (score 16):

Easy-to-follow steps: `git pull origin master` or `main` will give a fatal error:

> Couldn't find remote ref main

So below steps will work just fine.

1. `git init`
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m "initial commit"`
4. `git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/your-repo-name.git`
5. `git branch -M main`
6. `git push -u origin main`

Comment: Six magic command-line invocations. Why are they necessary? An explanation would be in order. From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68737730/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 8):

> Create a new repository on GitHub. To avoid errors, do not initialize
> the new repository with README, license, or gitignore files. You can
> add these files after your project has been pushed to GitHub. Open
> Terminal (for Mac users) or the command prompt (for Windows and Linux
> users).
>
> Change the current working directory to your local project.
>
> Initialize the local directory as a Git repository.
>
> `git init`
>  `#Add the files in your new local repository. This stages them for the first commit.`

> `git add`
> `# Adds the files in the local repository and stages them for commit. To unstage a file, use 'git reset HEAD YOUR-FILE'. Commit the files that you've staged in your local repository.`

> `git commit -m 'First commit'`
> `#Commits the tracked changes and prepares them to be pushed to a remote repository. To remove this commit and modify the file, use 'git reset --soft HEAD~1' and commit and add the file again.`

> 1. At the top of your GitHub repository's Quick Setup page, click [image] to copy the remote repository URL. At the top of your GitHub repository's Quick Setup
>    page, click  to copy the remote repository URL.
> 2. In the Command prompt, add the URL for the remote repository where your local repository will be pushed.

> `$ git remote add origin remote repository URL`  
> `# Sets the new remote git remote -v`
> `# Verifies the new remote URL Note: GitHub for Windows users should use the command git remote set-url origin instead of git remote add origin here. Push the changes in your local repository to GitHub.`

> `$ git push origin master`
> `# Pushes the changes in your local repository up to the remote repository you specified as the origin.`

Source attribution: *[Adding an existing project to GitHub using the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)*

Comment: in this case, c/p is better than just saying "answer is here".  IMHO.

Comment: IMHO, c/p is fine but the source is required since it might go obsolete.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me;

```
1- git init
2- git add .
3- git commit -m "Add all my files"
4- git remote add origin https://github.com/USER_NAME/FOLDER_NAME
5- git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
6- git push origin master
```

Comment: It's important especially for window users to download git first. I learned it the hard way. Mac users are so lucky.

Comment: @Alchemist21 But the hardest way give you the best destination ;)

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are on a Windows system like me and have Git installed. You can either run these commands by simple command prompt in the project directory or you can also use [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway).

Step 1:

Create a repository in Git manually. Give it whatever name you seem fit.

Step 2:

Come to your local project directory. If you want to publish your code to this new repository you just created, make sure that in the projects root directory there is no folder name .git. If there is, delete it.
Run command `git init`.

Step 3:

Run command

`git add .`

Step 4:

Run command

`git commit -m YourCommitName`

Step 5:

Run command

`git remote add YourRepositoryName https://github.com/YourUserName/YourRepositoryName.git`

Step 6:

Run Command

`git push --set-upstream YourRepositoryName master --force`

Please note that I am using the latest version of Git at the time of writing. Also note that I did not specify any particular branch to push the code into so it went to master. In step 6 the Git will ask you to authorize the command by asking you to enter username and password in a popup window.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open Git Bash.
2. Change the current working directory to your local project.
3. Initialize the local directory as a Git repository: `$ git init`
4. Add the files in your new local repository. This stages them for the first   commit: `$ git add .`
5. Commit the files that you've staged in your local repository: `$ git commit -m "First commit"`
6. At the top of your GitHub repository's Quick Setup page, click  to copy the remote repository URL.
7. In the Command prompt, add the URL for the remote repository where your local repository will be pushed : `$ git remote add origin remote repository URL`
8. Push the changes in your local repository to GitHub: `$ git push origin master`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please read [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for information on answering questions.  Also, it's better to try and answer questions that are new and don't have accepted answers rather then old questions with highly accepted answers.

Comment: @Kateract You inspired me to be kinder to new people. I'll use your post as a guideline.

Answer (score 5):

1. First you have to create an account on GitHub
2. Then create a new project - name that project as you want and then your project URL is shown
3. Now copy the URL
4. Then open a Command Prompt and go to the directory or folder which you want to upload using *cmd*
5. Then type the following commands

   ```
     git init
     git add .
     git commit -m "initial commit"
     git remote add origin PASTE URL
     git push -u origin master
   ```
6. Now check your GitHub account. The repository is successfully uploaded.

For *complete* guidance, you can [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psgrKFlNwTI&t).

Comment: On Windows, presumably (given 'cmd')?

Answer (score 4):

It took me like 1-2 hours to realize that I'm supposed to **create the repository at GitHub before** trying to push my local files to GitHub (or whatever, Git service you're using).

After trying to push, errors were like:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/project.git/' not found
```

I feel like an idiot, but I really would like to emphasize this for beginners like me. I just thought that my repository will be created automatically during the first push. I was so wrong.

You can see your *remotes* with this command:

```
git remote -v
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Steps to upload project to Git:

Step 1 - open cmd and change the current working directory to your project location.

Step 2 - Initialize your project directory as a Git repository.

```
git init
```

Step 3 - Add files in your local repository.

```
add .
```

Step 4 - Commit the files that you've staged in your local repository.

```
git commit -m "First commit"
```

Step 5 - Copy the remote repository URL.

Step 6 - Add the remote repository URL as origin in your local location.

```
git add origin copied_remote_repository_url
```

Step 7 - Confirm your origin is updated or not.

```
git remote show origin
```

Step 8 - Push the changed to your GitHub repository

```
git push origin master.
```

Comment: What about the full stop at the very end (in step 8)? It doesn't look right.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest thing for you to do would be to install [the Git plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) for [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29). It works more or less the same as the Eclipse CVS and SVN plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that Git is installed on your system. I'm explaining the process using windows OS [Although it shouldn't be OS dependent job]

Here is how I did:

1. Open the **cmd** (you can do with git bash as well if you've installed git bash).
2. Go to your project directory (where your project is located, it's essentially changing to directory either usiing `cd path` or through manual folder navigation).
3. Now type `git init`. This will initialize an empty repository if it is first time and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   For example: `git init`
4. Now type `git add <filename>`(if specific file) or `git add <filename1> <filename2> <filenameN>` (if specific but more than one files) or `git add .` (if you want to add all files) and enter.
5. Now type `git commit -m "commit message goes here"` and enter.

   (in case if you need to check the status you can do by typing `git status`) and enter.
6. Now type `git remote add origin  git_repository_url`

   (check `git remote -v` go check remote repository) and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. Now it's turn to push it to the remote repository [essentially taking all the changes from local git to cloud(github) `...git push origin master` and enter

   (if you get error you push it forcefully by typing `...git push -f origin master` and enter.

**NOTE** : master is the name of your master branch. If you've multiple branches, make sure that you select the name of the branch accordingly.

Now you're done with adding it to your remote repository from local computer. Refresh it and it will be there in your created repository's selected branch.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most useful thing you could do is to peruse the online book *[Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/)*. It's really a pretty decent read and gives you the conceptual context with which to execute things properly.

Answer (score 2):

Follow [the instructions from RishiKesh Pathak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799719/how-to-upload-a-project-to-github/27701083#27701083). You can even short the push command by inserting this command line one time only:

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

So next time instead of using `git push origin master` you just need:

```
git push
```

See details [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35974260/4058484).

Answer (score 2):

Download [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements).

It is available for Windows 7 (and later) and Mac, and it is highly recommended to upload files on GitHub via the interactive UI.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use Git is to actually start **Gitting**. Try out this website which makes you go step by step on what are the essential ways for performing functions on command line for pushing a project on GitHub.

This is called [try.github.io](https://try.github.io) or you could also take up a course on [Codecademy](https://codeacademy.com).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12257759)

Comment: @VinothKrishnan Agreed, will take care of it next time

Answer (score 1):

I did as follows;

1. git init
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "Your_message"
4. git remote add origin @your_git_repository
5. git push -u origin master

Of course you have to install Git.

Comment: What version of Git? On what system, incl. version, flavour, and edition?

Answer (score 1):

1. We need Git Bash
2. In the Git Bash Command Section:

   1. `ls`

      It will show your default location.
   2. `CD "C:\Users\user\Desktop\HTML"`

      We need to assign the project path.
   3. `git init`

      It will initialize the empty Git repository in *C:\Users\user\Desktop\HTML*
   4. `ls`

      It will list all file names.
   5. `git remote add origin https://github.com/repository/test.git`

      It is your https://github.com/repository/test.git is your repository path
   6. `git remote -v`

      To check whether we have fetch or push permission or not
   7. `git add .`

      If you use `.` then it means whatever we have in the particular folder publish all.
   8. `git commit -m "First time"`
   9. `git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 1):

### Upload a project from Visual Studio Code to GitHub

To upload your project in GitHub using Visual Studio Code, follow the following steps.

1. Open the Visual Studio Code. if you don't have the VSCode download: [Download Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)
2. In VSCode go to File-->Open Folder..
3. Go to Terminal-->New Terminal
4. Execute the following commands one by one after one another in order

`git init`

`git add .`

`git commit -m "First Commit"`

`git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/your-repo-name.git`

`git push origin master`

**Note:** in the above command `git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/your-repo-name.git` please change the bold sections with your **GitHub account name** and **your repository name**.

Answer (score 0):

You need an SSH connection and GitHub init into your project. I will explain under Linux machine.

Let's start with some easy stuff: navigate into your project in the terminal, and use:

```
git init
git add .
git commit
```

Now let's add SSH into your machine:

use

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Copy the public key, and then add it to your GitHub repository:

`Deploy keys ->  add one`

Back to your machine project, now launch:

```
git push origin master
```

if there is an error, configure your *.github/config* file by

```
nano .github/config
```

And change the URL to the SSH one by:

```
url = git@github.com:username/repo....
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) to push your code/make changes instead of uploading files directly on GitHub (it is less prone to errors and is quite comfortable at times - takes less time as well!). For doing so, you may follow the below given steps:

1. Download and install the latest version of Git Bash [from here](https://git-scm.com/).
2. Right-click on any desired location on your system.
3. Click “Git Bash Here”.
4. `git config --global user.name “your name”`
5. `git config --global user.email “your email”`
6. Go back to your GitHub account – open your project – click on “clone” – copy HTTPS link.
7. `git clone PASTE HTTPS LINK`.
8. A clone of your GitHub project will be created on your computer location.
9. Open the folder and paste your content.
10. Make sure content is not empty.
11. Right-click inside the cloned folder where you have pasted your content.
12. Click “Git Bash Here” again.
13. You will find (master) appearing after your location address.
14. `git add .`
15. Try `git status` to check if all your changes are marked in green.
16. `git commit --m “Some message”`
17. `git push origin master`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to know few command im cmd to push or pull any directory to/from github.
Command to push/upload any project or code to the git hub.

First reach to the working directory or project directory which you need to upload.

> to check the correct working directory

```
ls
```

> to initialize the git in the directory

```
git init
```

> to the check that **git init** worked or not

```
ls -a //this command shows hidden files
```

> Using above command you will find file added in you directory.

```
 ./   ../   .git/
```

> the above is not a command you can skip it.
> Now add the files of working directory to commit

```
git add .
```

> then use commit command and name that commit for reference

```
git commit -m "Commit Name"
```

> Before final step you need to go to the github website and create a new repository and copy the url of the repository

```
git remote add main https://github.com/username/repositoryName.git
```

> now command to upload the directory

```
git push -u main
```

**Note: the name "main" is the name that can be change as per user**

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by using the command `git clone`.

it will save you a lot of time and headache not to mention the overall less commands to set things up and get started.

Here are the steps:

1. create a new repo on github (after signing in)
   https://github.com/new
2. on your computer (local env), open the command line (terminal) in the directory in which you'd like to save your project (it must be an empty folder).
3. type in the command `git clone ${your repo url}` (for example: `git clone https://github.com/username/test-repo.git`)
4. that's it

In order to add files to your remote repo (upload to your github repo the latest files):

1. `git add .` (add all edited files)
2. `git commit -m "your comment here"`
3. `git push origin master` (master is the main branch name)

Answer (score -2):

For uploading a new project into Git (first you need to have the local code base of the project and the Git repository where you will be uploading project. In Git, you need to have your credentials).

1. List item
2. Open [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway)
3. Go to the directory where you have the code base (project location)

   cd to project location

   cd /*/***/*****/*****

   Then here you need to execute Git commands.
4. `git init`

   Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then you will see something like this below.

   The initialized empty Git repository in *:/***/****/*****/.git/, so `git init` will initialize the empty Git repository at local
5. `git add .`

   Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   The above command will add all the directories, subdirectories, files, etc.

   You will see something like this:

   > warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in **************. 
   > The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
6. `git commit -m "first commit"`

   Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. -m provided option for adding comment.

   It will commit the code to the stage environment.

   You will see some thing like this:

   > [master (root-commit) 34a28f6] adding ********
   > warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in c*******.
   > The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

   > ---
   >
   > ---
   >
   > 27 files changed, 3724 insertions(+)
   > create mode 100644 *****
   > create mode 100644 *****
   > create mode 100644 *****
7. `git remote add origin`

   http://username@git:repopath.git

   Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will add to the repository.
8. `git push -u origin master`

   Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   This will upload all from local to repository in this step you need to enter password for the repository where you will be uploading the code.

   You will see some thing like this below:

   > Counting objects: 33, done. 
   > Delta compression using up to 12 threads. 
   > Compressing objects: 100% (32/32), done. 
   > Writing objects: 100% (33/33), 20.10 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done. 
   > Total 33 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0) 
   > To http://username@git:repolocation.git \
   >
   > - [new branch]      master -> master 
   >   Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.

Comment: On Windows, presumably?