# How to create a local repository and upload to repository on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I just started using GitHub and I'm just looking for simple and straightforward set of steps to upload a project on my local machine to a repository I created on the GitHub website.

I tried this method from a previous question here [How to upload a project to Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799719/how-to-upload-a-project-to-github) but when I get to the last step `git push origin master` I get these errors `fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` I don't understand why this is happening as I'm following the instructions to the letter.

This is how I execute the upload from creation of local repository to push:

```
cd C:\Users\Brian Smith\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\KinectKickboxingBVversion1

git init

git add KinectKickboxingBVversion1

git commit -m "adding files". 

git remote add originNew https://github.com/BrianJSmith/College_Kinect_Project.git

git push origin master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/BrianJSmith/College_Kinect_Project.git
```

Not `originNew`.

Comment: Lol I think I need to take a break for a while,thanks