# Laravel 5.2 - How do I release my Web App to GitHub?

Tags: php, laravel, github, laravel-5

So I’ve just finished developing my Laravel 5.2 web application that uses AdminLTE. It is an Asset Management System with some budget and invoice functionality, which will assist me in making my full-time job as a Systems Manager easier.

It’s not the most complicated app, but I’m proud of it, so I want to share it on GitHub, so others might be able to make use of it, as well as having my code available for future when I start applying for development jobs.

Now I’ve tried my best Google skills, but I just cannot figure out how to go about sharing my code on GitHub. I've used Bitbucket during my development phases, as I wanted to keep it private.

If anyone can please direct in the right direction about what steps I should be taking now to actually share my app out there. Should I be looking at something like Packagist instead, as I’m sure I’m not supposed share Laravel along with my web app. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This question is not about how to upload my project to GitHub, but specifically about what the correct procedure is for Laravel projects and how to share them for others to easily use.

Comment: 1. Have you created a gitbub repo and moved the code to it ? 2. Do you have ssh access ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload a project to Github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799719/how-to-upload-a-project-to-github)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question of mine is more related to the correct way of putting a Laravel App out there. Do I just upload the entire folder and all it's contents to GitHub, like I've done here - https://github.com/TTFerreira/ivd-assets or is there a more specific way that you handle it?

Comment: The only things that shouldn't get uploaded are your `.env` file (as there may be sensitive information like database credentials) and your `/vendor` file. Take a look at your `.gitignore` file to see what is being excluded. That being said, make sure your `readme.md` has ***detailed*** instructions on the installation process. Also, if you have an required database structures, make sure your `migrations` are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a project repo and upload all your project code there.

If you didn't modify any core file in `vendor` directory, then upload the all code except `vendor` directory.

once uploaded, add up some `readme.md` file to tell some guideline/instruction for installation the project.

make your repo public so other can access it