# Connecting a local existing directory to an existing Git remote ropository

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Here is my scenario:

A user has a local directory with many files and folders in it.   This local directory is the same as a repository that already exists in a remote repo. but this local directory is NOT under git source control.

I wondered if there was a way that a user would be able to associate this local directory to that remote repository.

** I realize that a dirty solution to this is to make a new folder locally and associate that with the the remote repository and then move all of the existing files into that new folder but I was wondering if that is the only way or if there is a specific command or process that is done that is less of a "hack".

To be clear, this users local folder might have some changes in his local directories files may need to be pushed to the remote so that they are not lost.

I have generally used sourcetree but that is not something I would feel is a requirement.

Comment: Which ide are you using? If you are using IntelliJ there is an option in VCS add project to git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload a project to Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799719/how-to-upload-a-project-to-github)

Comment: I am using various IDEs.    The reason I say that is some of our projects are .Net related, some Java, some are sql scripts, others are various other types so this needs to be an answer not dependent on any particular, however, if there was a solution that would have lent itself to a specif tool I might have been open to it.

Comment: then I think you should go for git bash it will let you do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done "in place"; I can't say whether you'll consider this approach a hack nonetheless, but it's as direct an approach as I can think of...

First, it sounds like his working copy is not a git repo at all.  In that case, you can create the git repo "in place" on his working tree

```
git init
```

At this point his working copy will show up as untracked files in this new repo.  Now associate the repo with the origin and fetch the history.

```
git remote add origin <origin-url>
git fetch
```

where `<origin-url>` is the same url you would use to clone.

At this point, you still have an "unborn" `master` branch and no other local branches; you still have the local working copy as untracked changes; and you have remote tracking refs for everything on the remote.

The next thing I'd do is something along the lines of

```
git add .
git diff origin/master
```

(I'm assuming here that if the local version is a modified copy of the code, it's modified *from* what's on `origin/master`.  If not, then you need to at least know what the "correct" parent commit would be, and substitute a reference to that commit.  I'll continue assuming `origin/master` for now, but feel free to comment if this is wrong and I can try to update accordingly.)

Here we're populating the index and comparing it to the remote's version, because if nothing is different, then you're done.  Just wipe the index and work tree and checkout `master` (which will create local `master` and set it up to track `origin/master`).

But it sounds like you don't think that's the case; so if you *do* see differences, you need to create a new commit.  The slightly tricky part is getting `git` to understand that this new state is just a child state of the existing `origin/master` commit.

There are several ways to do that, and I'm sure opinions will vary on which way is best.  A simple approach (but it does use some less-familiar commands) would be

```
git merge $(git commit-tree -p origin/master -m "Commit Message" $(git write-tree))
```

...which probably could stand a little explanation.

So first this creates a new `TREE` (a snapshot of the project content) based on the index.  Because we did a `git add .` before doing `git diff`, the index reflects the local version.  This would print to standard output the ID of the new `TREE` object.

We pass that ID to `git commit-tree`, which creates a `COMMIT` object with the given parent (again I'm assuming `origin/master`), commit message (fill in something appropriate after `-m`), and `TREE` (the one we just created from the index).  That would print to standard output the ID of the new `COMMIT` object.

Then we merge the new `COMMIT` object into the current (unborn) `master` branch, which is a slightly weird thing to do but works like a fast-forward onto the specified `COMMIT`.  So  now you have

```
x -- x -- O <--(origin/master)
           \
            L <--(master)
```

where `L` will have content equal to the local copy; so it looks just like you had started from `O` and made the local changes.  You can `push` normally at this point.

Comment: Thanks this seems very explained.   I will give it a try when I get an opportunity. And if it satisfies my need I will mark accordingly.