# Upload project from android studio to github

Tags: android-studio, github, upload

i tried to use VCS > Import into version control > Share project on GitHub. https://snipboard.io/aTBxe9.jpg

However i got an error https://snipboard.io/6Eashw.jpg . then i used https://stackoverflow.com/a/27701083/15334005 and followed all the steps yet none of my files appear on github.

https://snipboard.io/7sSbcq.jpg

i would share any further information required. if someone provide me an updated ist of instruction to be followed since both github and android studio have changed w.r.t previous answer i promise to update the steps for newer version and changes below this line as i learn to do it for use of future people.

Answer (score 0):

Will update my answer as i learn and will keep this answer updated wrt newer version and changes for future users.