# How to Push Magento 2 from My PC to github

Tags: github, magento, magento2, gitignore, magento2.4

My store is ready 100% and Now I wanna push it to GitHub but I cant, plz tell me steps in detail.
I will be really thanks full to you,

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a Github account and no repo yet, you can follow the steps detailed out [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-locally-hosted-code-to-github)

Please detail out your requirement or issues instead of a generic question.

Answer (score 0):

1. git clone git_url
2. git check branch
3. git add *
4. git commit
5. git push origin branch_name
6. change env file in the database name, username, password

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing great!

Please follow the steps mentioned in the below link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12800042/7344580

***Note:*** Please see an answer given by **Burhan Khalid**

Thanks