# Can't access the pages uploaded from 'dist' folder

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I made a react project, using babel and webpack. After transpiling the main.jsx(my jsx file name) using Babel, i used the command 'npx webpack' i got the main.js file as well as the output but when i upload the main.js ,index.html and style.css in github the page is not working.
Please tell me the steps i need to perform and also if webpack production will fix this?

Answer (score 1):

to build for production you need to run this command
`npm run build` inside your project folder,
which will create a new folder called "dist" that will contain all your production code.
you can check the react documentation for more information about this step,
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/
then, upload it to GitHub you can follow these steps
[How to upload a project to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799719/how-to-upload-a-project-to-github)

keep in mind that files that you upload must be in the same structure tree as in the dist folder
for example:
if it is like this:

```
dist/index.html
dist/assets/index.css
dist/assets/index.js
```

you can't upload it to GitHub (if you will upload it manually not using Git) as this:

```
index.html
index.css
index.js
```

you must keep the tree structure as in the dist folder.