# How do I push to a repository in github in a situation like this?

Tags: git, github

I write my notes in Joplin. I export them as `.md` (markdown). It turns them into two folders: `Resources` consists of images. `NGINX@HOME` consists of markdown file.

```
Resources
NGINX@HOME (The name of my note book)
```

Now, I push them into github using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63645193/19901123). Next, I write 2nd note on NGINX. I write it in the same notebook as earlier. I export it as `.md`. Again it makes the two folders with same name as above because the notebook is same.

Now, I want to to push that code to github to the same repository. But when I try it I get various errors.

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<my_github_id>/my_notes.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I do `git pull origin main` but it still fails to upload.

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Apparently, you have two unrelated git histories. For your "2nd note", did you create a _new_ local git repo, or you continue using (or make a clone of) the original repo?

Comment: I created a new local git repo.

Comment: I see. Do you care about preserving commit history in the second repo? Or do you just want to add the new files to the original repo?

Comment: As a side note, why this is happening and what you should do going forward may make a lot more sense if you [read up on git itself](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Comment: I just want to add the new files to the original repo. @Brian61354270 I'll immediately start learning from that book. Thank you for recommending it.

Answer (score -4):

You should first resolve your merges and Then again use

```
git add .
git commit -m ""
git push origin main
```

Comment: What's the full process?

Comment: @zeeshanseikh You can disregard this answer. It isn't at all relevant to your problem.