# HTTPS credentials: obfuscate console or pop-up window input

Tags: r, git, github, https, obfuscation

Inspired by this [awesome post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) on a Git branching model and [this one](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pete-otaqui/4188238/raw/9675e75948294fd3b05186f30af6ff97e7e9e47e/bumpversion.sh) on what a version bumping script actually does, I went about creating my own [Git](http://git-scm.com/) version bumping routine which resulted in a little package called [bumpr](https://github.com/Rappster/bumpr).

However, I don't like the current way of handling ([GitHub](https://github.com/)) HTTPS credentials. I'm using the solution stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648737/use-r-to-push-local-repo-to-github-on-windows) and it works great, but I don't like the fact that I need to store my credentials in plain text in this `_netrc` file.

So I wondered:

1. if one could also obfuscate console input when prompting via `readline()`, `scan()` or the like in much the same way as when using the Git shell. See code of [`/R/bump.r`](https://github.com/Rappster/bumpr/blob/master/R/bump.r) at line 454:

   ```
   input <- readline(paste0("Password for 'https://", 
     git_user_email, "@github.com': "))
   idx <- ifelse(grepl("\\D", input), input, NA)
   if (is.na(idx)){
     message("Empty password")
     message("Exiting")
     return(character())
   }
   git_https_password <- input
   ```
2. how RStudio realizes that a "Insert credentials" box pops up when pushing to a remote Git repository and how they obfuscate the password entry.
3. if file `_netrc` is something closely related to the [GitHub](https://github.com/) API or if this works for HTTPS requests in general

Comment: I once did battle with GitHub API and through the combined efforts of many great minds produced one little R function to send a local repo to GitHub as a new repo.  The code uses `_netcr`.  It may be of use to you https://github.com/trinker/qdapTools/blob/master/R/repo2github.R  Can't promise it's best practice but there may be useful stuff in there.

Comment: Thanks man. It was your effort in the post I linked to that got me going in the first place! :-) I'll check that out, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah the best I could come up with is to store the password in the user's home directory.  Dason K. advised this over the temp as it may be accessed by others (if I remember correctly).  The function attempts to delete the script but this can't be guaranteed. I suppose you could check to see if it was deleted with `file.exists` but even then if the function errored before this step the deletion may not occur.

Comment: For github, you should be using personal access tokens, e.g. https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/R/github.R#L38

Comment: Aha! Thanks Hadley, didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Git has a mechanism to store, cache or prompt for credentials. Please read http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.

Within a script, you can use the `git credential` command to access it: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential