# How to clone a git-project to create a different repo?

Tags: git, github

I've got a Github project (https://github.com/gbrits/yeoman-less) that I'd like to use as a quickstart for some other projects. Each of these other projects need to get their own repo.

So `git clone` https://github.com/gbrits/yeoman-less (alone) doesn't work, since I need to do something like change the origin after the clone to point to a different remote endpoint.

Related: hos would you create a remote origin in github from the commandline, instead of having to manually create it and then linking it up in the commandline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy it appears.

**First clone**

```
git clone git://..
```

Optionally change name of local dir.

**intermezzo**: create new remote github repo (from website) or from command-line (see below): (from [Is it possible to create a remote repo on GitHub from the CLI without opening browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423777/is-it-possible-to-create-a-remote-repo-on-github-from-the-cli-without-ssh/10325316#10325316_)

```
curl -u 'USER:PASS' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"REPO"}'
git remote add origin git@github.com:USER/REPO.git
git push origin master
```

**Change origin**

`git remote set-url origin git://<new repo>`

**And push**

`git push -u origin master`