# Create github repo bash file, NOT be prompted for password

Tags: bash, curl, github, repository

I need to be able to create github repositories via bash scripts that run from a php page, so I need to be able to pass the password in the curl command or the API Key.

However I can not seem to find the API key as I believe this may be redundant now with V3 of the github API

I followed [Is it possible to create a remote repo on GitHub from the CLI without opening browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423777/is-it-possible-to-create-a-remote-repo-on-github-from-the-cli-without-ssh/10325316#10325316) and it got me as far as being prompted for the password

Bash file looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
a=$1
curl="-u 'USERNAME' -p 'PASSWORD' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{\"name\":\""$a"\"}'"
curl $curl
```

This does not work as it is not liking the -p parameter it seems, tried `-u 'USERNAME:PASSWORD'` and it did not like that either and I can not seem to find the answer on github pages.  Ideally I would use the API key as this would not leave my repo password exposed in my bash file correct?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl -u 'dmalikov:my_password' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"HI"}'` works fine for me, now I have this [`HI`](https://github.com/dmalikov/HI) repo.

Comment: ok the issue seems to be that I want to pass a variable in as the name of the repo. By calling $curl the string it changes the username to be enclosed in ''. Your way works but I now need to find how to pass a variable into the JSON.  Many thanks for looking into

Comment: Got everything sorted :) for reference I used the command: `curl -u 'USERNME:PASSWORD' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"'"$repoName"'"}'`