# Best and easy way to create Git Repository from the CLi (using hub)

Tags: git, unix, github, command-line-interface, repository

So if you are like me, you must have got **really tired** of going to the browser every time to create a repo for your many ideas/projects and using GIT rest api syntax is your thing. So here is your break!

Comment: It does not use git's rest api syntax but "hub" a github cli wrapper, thats the difference

Comment: [One of the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13366414/1734130) to linked question also mentions hub tool.

Comment: Seen, I just elaborated more, made it your 1st and best option, in this case especially for beginners.

Comment: Please write a proper question to justify your answer.

Comment: I get the right answer through this question. So, it is a valid post that allows other users to find the right solution.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a the best and shortest way possible -- **hub**
`**hub** is a command-line wrapper for git that makes you better at GitHub.`

LINK to install -- http://hub.github.com/
`you will get installation instructions first thing on the landing page`

you will need to alias it like this so as not to get confused or forget the command later on:
`$ alias git=hub  --> in the CLi`

Then you are good to go in creating a repo, **you must init 1st though, fails most of the time if you havent.**

`git init`

then

`git create` -- this will create a **repo** with the name of the folder that your project is wrapped in.

for custom repo name

`git create myCustomRepoName`

You can also add the description and homepage link when creating the repo

`git create myCustomRepoName -d "my greatest app for the world" -h "http://prittynote.com"`

You will get more Cli methods from the site. CHEERS GUYS.