# How to create a github.com repository over HTTP API?

Tags: github, github-api

According to the [general instruction to the github.com API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) and the [explanation of the create command](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create)

```
curl -u "krichter722" https://api.github.com # works (returns JSON response)
curl -d '{"name":"test"}' https://api.github.com/user/repos/
```

should work and create a repository, but the second command fails with

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

I found [Using `curl` to create a repo on GitHub.com with two-factor authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747469/using-curl-to-create-a-repo-on-github-com) which resolves an issue caused by missing parts in the request for two-factor authentication.

Other questions, like ["Bad Credentials" when attempting to create a GitHub repo through the CLI using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443135/bad-credentials-when-attempting-to-create-a-github-repo-through-the-cli-using), indicate that the URL is correct (the creation fails due to bad credentials according to error message in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:-

```
curl -u "$username:$token" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"'$repo_name'"}'
```

You can find personal access token in [Github Settings -> Application](https://github.com/settings/applications), replace username with your username and repo_name with repository name.

Note:- You might need to create personal access token if you haven't used it earlier.

Comment: It's the github.com login password instead of `$token` and the link to create a token is https://github.com/settings/tokens. The docs read like one needs to authenticate first and then request the API URL, but the trick is to invoke `curl` with both `-u` and `-d` options. Confirmed to work with `python`'s `request` modules as well.