# Create new repo by 'git remote add origin' and 'push'

Tags: git, github

When creating a local repo and trying to push it to `github`, ending up with an issue:

> ```
> ERROR: Repository not found.
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
> ```

My steps are standard - that what gitHub Help suggests to go with.

```
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:MyUser/my-samples.git
git push -u origin master
```

Then: `git push -u origin master`

Q: **How can I push new repo/branch to the `github`?**

> Just clarifying: I wan to create New repository from command line
>   remotely - it does not exist yet on my github.

Basically I'm trying to perform [11th step](http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/11) on http://try.github.io/

Btw. when I try to use `https://` instead of just `git@github.com:...` (following that steps) I end up having **403 error**.

If I use `"ssh://"`, [adding my keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) on github, I end up having `Repository not found error`. But that test **sh -T git@github.com** passes **successfully**,

So **UPDATE**: **yes I've checked my connection**.

Comment: The `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly` error happens frequently when you can't connect to the remote host (in this case GitHub), so that may be your issue. What happens when you try to ping GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a repo on github to be able to push your changes to it. Bare repos are not initialized automatically. Otherwise spelling mistakes can lead to undesirable creation of new repos.

Comment: That's the thing - I'm expecting to create new repo on github without a need to go to it via browser.

Answer (score 3):

So, I guess a simple answer is: **it is impossible to create repo remotely** by **git remote add** and **push** command.

Thus, when I do: `git remote add origin git@github.com:MyUser/my-samples.git`

It does **NOT** mean it is going to create NEW repo on the REMOTE host. It means **it is going to link my `origin master` branch to remote one**, which is supposed to be existing at that moment.

Then, probably there is an command that would create a repo/project remotely.

But it is different one - **not git remote add** .. and **then push.**

That being said, I consider +Akash Agrawal's corrent. Answering my question just to make it clear for myself.

--

That answers my question how to create it remotelly from command line: [Is it possible to create a remote repo on GitHub from the CLI without opening browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423777/is-it-possible-to-create-a-remote-repo-on-github-from-the-cli-without-ssh):

```
curl -u 'USER' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"REPO"}'
```

Or HUB:
 http://hub.github.com/

```
# create a repo for a new project
$ git init
$ git add . && git commit -m "It begins."
$ git create -d "My new thing"
→ (creates a new project on GitHub with the name of current directory)
$ git push origin master
```