# Why does GitHub not let us create our repositories using the command line out-of-the-box?

Tags: git, curl, github

Wouldn't it be nice if GitHub built this into Git Shell?

Apparently [Stack Overflow says we have to use cURL to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423777/is-it-possible-to-create-a-remote-repo-on-github-from-the-cli-without-ssh/10325316#10325316).

```
curl -u 'USER' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"REPO"}'
# Remember replace USER with your username and REPO with your repository/application name!
git remote add origin git@github.com:USER/REPO.git
git push origin master
```

But it doesn't work for me. I get a 401 Unauthorized if I use this method:
[image]

Note: --cacert is just to include a cert for SSL in my root directory

Hrm. Okay. So then I found out that the [official docs](https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/#create-a-repository) do it with an authorization token:

```
$ curl -i -H 'Authorization: token 5199831f4dd3b79e7c5b7e0ebe75d67aa66e79d4' \
    -d '{ \
        "name": "blog", \
        "auto_init": true, \
        "private": true, \
        "gitignore_template": "nanoc" \
      }' \
    https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Note: only "name" is required in the -d JSON http body according to [developer.github.com/v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#input). We can leave out everything else and just type:

```
$ curl -i -H 'Authorization: token 5199831f4dd3b79e7c5b7e0ebe75d67aa66e79d4' \
    -d '{ \
        "name": "new_repo_name", \
      }' \
    https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Problem is... typing in that long token (you can't CTRL-V in cmd) is going to defeat the purpose of using the CLI in the first place.

**EDIT**

I found [hub](https://github.com/github/hub) to be a very good solution. Just install it, navigate to your github repo folder, and create a repo like this:

```
hub create new_repo_name
```

And we're done and ready for commits and pushes. No complaints so far.

Comment: Not an authoritive answer, but probably because otherwise every typo in the url could make a repository, leading into lots of unwanted extra repositories

Comment: @Leigh https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/#create-a-repository You can see the curl command there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your first question: This is not a “restriction” by github, but by git. Git is not specifically designed for github and thus has no support for pushing to non-existent repositories. I think github could hack that in on the server side, but that would just create a repo for every typo etc, as Ikke pointed out.

If you want nicer command-line support, you can use github’s `hub` tool: https://github.com/github/hub. Using that, you can create a repo with `hub create`.

Alternatively you could just create a small shell script yourself that contains all the required code and just takes the repository name as parameter.

Comment: Alright managed to create it via hub. Seems like the best way to go about it for now. They should've just built it in.

Comment: @Geoyws, you're missing the point. Git and GitHub are different things. GitHub did not create Git. GitHub is built *on top of* Git. The `git` command line tool was not created by GitHub, but by many developers around the world, largely working for free, and therefore has no support for GitHub's proprietary features. `hub` is GitHub's way of adding proprietary features to the command line.