# Using `curl` to create a repo on GitHub.com with two-factor authentication

Tags: git, http, curl, github

I'm having problems using `curl` to create a repo on my GitHub.com account (no ssh).

I have created a basic static local site using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) which I want to push to the GitHub.com repo (I want to host the site on `<username>.github.io` and according to the instructions on GitHub pages the repo must have the same name as the folder containing the local site.

I have two-factor authentication enabled for the GitHub login, so following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20598750/997225) I am passing an OTP/token (generated on [Applications settings](https://github.com/settings/applications) in the request header using the  option `-H "X-GitHub-OTP":<token>`.  I can log in (this post previously raised an issue about the Github login not working, which was due to not closing the string `"X-GitHub-OTP"` properly), but now the login works but I now receive a response with a 400 code.  Here is the `curl` command I am used:

```
$username="<username>"
$reponame="$username.github.io"
$token="<token>"
$apidom="https://api.github.com/user/repos/"
$curl -u $username -H '{"X-GitHub-OTPOTP":$token}' -d '{"name":$reponame,"description":$repodesc}' $apidom
```

and the response message:

```
<p><strong>We didn't receive a proper request from your browser.</strong></p>
<p>Sorry about that. Please try refreshing and contact us if the problem persists.</p>
<div id="suggestions">
<a href="https://github.com/contact">Contact Support</a> &mdash;
<a href="https://status.github.com">GitHub Status</a> &mdash;
<a href="https://twitter.com/githubstatus">@githubstatus</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two-factor authentication enabled, you will need to [send a special HTTP header](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#working-with-two-factor-authentication):

> In addition to the Basic Authentication credentials, you must send the user’s authentication code (i.e., one-time password) in the `X-GitHub-OTP` header. Because these authentication codes expire quickly, we recommend using the Authorizations API to [create an access token](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#create-a-new-authorization) and using that token to [authenticate via OAuth](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) for most API access.
>
> Alternately, you can create access tokens from the Personal Access Token section of your [application settings page](https://github.com/settings/applications).

Comment: Thanks, I created personal token using Settings but it's still not working, using the same curl command format (with correct password and token) I'm now getting this message:
    `{
    "message": "Must specify two-factor authentication OTP code.",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/auth#working-with-two-factor-authentication"
    }`

Comment: @ramius, the URL in that error message is the same one I linked to in my answer. Can you edit your question to clarify exactly what you have done to generate this message?

Comment: Hi, sure, that's fine.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20443135/997225) seems identical.  I'll have a look later.

Comment: thanks but I'm having another problem with the HTTP response from the `curl` statement, as described in my updated question.  ANy help would be appreciated.

Comment: @ramius, I just saw this comment. But you have accepted the answer... Is everything working now?

Comment: Well, yes and no - manually creating the remote repo this way does still not work (I created the repo directly on GitHub.com), but
I accepted the answer because it indicates what the problem may be - sending the OTP code in the header using `-H '{"X-GitHub-OTPOTP":$token}` with `curl`.  The HTTP response, which I have stored, indicates that the browser does not form the request correctly, but as you can see from the session output above I am doing exactly what you have suggested, ref. also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20598750/997225).

Comment: Could it be browser specific (I use Firefox v. 34.0 and some plugins like HTTPS Everywhere)?

Comment: @ramius, why would your web browser have anything to do with this? Aren't you running `curl` on the command-line?

Comment: CL of course, I don't know why I mentioned the browser, must have been thinking about another post.  I've solved the problem - kind of - by creating the repo directory on GitHub.com and was able to do a `git push` from local.

There's also appears to be good solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24282548/997225).

Answer (score 1):

Two factor authentication

```
curl -u "YOUR_USERNAME_HERE" \
    -H "X-Github-OTP:YOUR_OTP_CODE_HERE" \
    https://api.github.com/user/repos
    -d '{"name": "test"}'
```

Normal authentication

```
curl -u "YOUR_USERNAME_HERE" \
    -H https://api.github.com/user/repos \
    -d '{"name":"Your repo name here"}'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your answers in future.