# Clone a local repository into github

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I am a git newbie. Please bare me if my question is silly.
I created a repository nameed "testrepo" in github.com (GUI) and added a readme file.(committed).

if i issue this command "git clone https://github.com/username/testrepo.git" from my local desktop machine, it creates a new repository in the same name (testrepo) with all the content. (readme file). I understood this. As the name says, it is exactly cloning the remote repository (not cloning a branch in a repo) into local machine.

My question is i created a local repository named "testrepo2" by issuing a command "git init testrepo2". I added some files and i committed the changes.

Now thru some command i want to export this entire repository (testrepo2) to my github.com account. To be precise i dont want to create a repository manually in github.com and push the local changes to that. I want to push the entire local repo to the remote.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is most probably a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423777/is-it-possible-to-create-a-remote-repo-on-github-from-the-cli-without-ssh

Comment: @Saravana, did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Github repo from the command line using their API.

Please try:

```
curl -u 'USERNAME' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"testrepo2"}' #Replace USERNAME by your Github username

git remote add origin https://github.com/username/testrepo2.git #to add the remote
git push origin master #to push your commits
```

Please see: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create

Comment: Hey, I am sorry. What u suggested is adding the new files into the existing testrepo repository. thats not what i want. I want to a new repository to be created in github,com with the name testrepo2.

Comment: So your question is how to create a github repo from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to know, how you can add a repository to your Github-account completely from the command line.
As far as I know, you can't. At least not without additional tools like the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create).

The Github help pages address the issue of adding a (locally) existing repository to your account [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/). The first step is always to create a repository via the web interface.

When you have created an empty repository on GitHub and a existing repo with some commits locally, you can push your work with the following commands:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/myUserName/testrepo2.git
git push origin master
```

This adds your Github-repo as the new remote named 'origin'.

Comment: Yes. I think i can refine my question as u said. How to create a new repository in github.com completely from command line.