# Create a GitHub repository from command line

Tags: git, github, repository

I have been trying to push my local repo changes to github from command line. I have been away from git for a while now so I don't remember a few things. For the past hour I have been trying to push the repo without creating a remote repo on Github.com. As far as I remember, git push origin master/ git push is enough to push the local changes and if necessary create a repo on the remote server. However git push wouldn't let me push and automatically create the repo.

So to save time, I created remote repo on github.com and add the remote repo url using

`git remote add origin https://mygithubrepoUrl.com`

and it worked.

Is it necessary to create remote repo on Github and then add this url from command line to push changes? Can't Git automatically create repo and push changes?

Comment: Yes, I believe this is necessary, and creating the repo remotely and then adding `origin` locally is the normal workflow.

Comment: The below post has the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423777/is-it-possible-to-create-a-remote-repo-on-github-from-the-cli-without-opening-br

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create a remote repo on GitHub from the CLI without opening browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423777/is-it-possible-to-create-a-remote-repo-on-github-from-the-cli-without-opening-br)

Answer (score 20):

You need to create the repo before pushing, but there's [`hub`](https://hub.github.com/) that automates this for you:

```
git init newRepo
cd newRepo
hub create
```

Use the `-p` switch to `hub create` to create a private repository. To push the local `master` branch, issue:

```
git push -u origin HEAD
```

The tool can also create pull requests, open the project page, check the CI status, clone existing repos by specifying only `username/repo`, and a few more things.

The project page suggests aliasing `git` to `hub` (because the latter forwards unknown commands to `git`), but I don't recommend this, even if just to distinguish "bare" Git commands from the `hub` candy.

Comment: you need to install hub for your environment from here https://github.com/github/hub#installation first

Comment: can it fetch username and password from saved config file?

Comment: You need to authenticate once, this stores a token in the user profile that is later used to access GitHub.

Answer (score 20):

[**cli.github.com**](https://cli.github.com/) is now the successor of hub.

It allows for repository creation from command line, since [cli 0.6](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v0.6.0), and [PR 547](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/547)

Create a new GitHub repository.

> ### Usage:
>
> Create a new GitHub repository.
>
> Use the "`ORG/NAME`" syntax to create a repository within your organization.
>
> ```
> gh repo create [<name>] [flags]
> ```

> ### Flags:
>
> ```
> -d, --description string   Description of repository
>     --enable-issues        Enable issues in the new repository (default true)
>     --enable-wiki          Enable wiki in the new repository (default true)
> -h, --homepage string      Repository home page URL
>     --public               Make the new repository public
> -t, --team string          The name of the organization team to be granted access
> ```

> ### Global Flags:
>
> ```
>  --help                  Show help for command
>  -R, --repo OWNER/REPO   Select another repository using the OWNER/REPO format
> ```

---

As noted by [itsgus.dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12686744/itsgus-dev) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124997/create-a-github-repository-from-command-line/60573319?noredirect=1#comment128974081_60573319):

> Either `--public`, `--private` or `--internal` flags are required when not running interactively.

Comment: @itsgus.dev Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: But what if I just want to continue using standard vanilla everywhere `git` and not download and start using a different GitHub-specific tool just for my git work on GitHub?

Comment: @NeilG The operations covered by `gh` are wrappers around GitHub API calls and are not covered by native `git` commands. Doing so without `gh` means using `curl`.

Comment: Thanks @VonC - so I take that as confirmation that GitHub does not support repo creation using vanilla `git`. You need the GitHub specific command.

Comment: @NeilG Exactly, that is the idea. Repo creation on GitHub is done through its REST API, hence `curl` or `gh`, not `git`.

Answer (score 8):

Github API should make work.

First create repo using `curl` and API
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create

something like:
`curl -u 'username' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"repository name"}'`

and then you can add remote and push as you have described before:

`git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repository_name.git && git push origin master`

Comment: [Github API create](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create) states that whilst two endpoints exist for creating a new repo (i.e. one for **user accounts** and one for **organization accounts**), they have only enabled the **organization accounts** endpoint. Example `curl --user 'username' https://api.github.com/username/repos --request POST --data '{"name":"newreponame"}' --verbose` returns `404 Not Found`,
whereas `curl --user 'username' https://api.github.com/orgs/orgname/repos -d '{"name":"newreponame"}'` returns `201 Created`. Use [hub](https://github.com/github/hub) instead.

Answer (score 3):

The [answer by mickiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35128644/) using the REST API via `curl` has numerous deficiencies which are addressed in this answer. Notably, this answer:

1. authorizes against GitHub using the necessary [token authorization](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/), not the obsolete password authentication
2. makes `curl` exit with a nonzero code in case of an error (via `-f`)
3. parameterizes the repo name
4. makes a private repo (default is public)

First, [obtain a token](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new) with access to the `repo` scope.

```
REPO_NAME=foo1
GITHUB_TOKEN=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  # Enter your own.

curl -f -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "{\"name\": \"${REPO_NAME}\", \"private\": true}"
```

This answer is relevant only for creating a repository under a [user](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user). The request for creating a repository under an [organization](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#create-an-organization-repository) is slightly different.

If you don't mind installing the GitHub CLI, refer to the [answer by VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60573319/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

First [install GitHub cli](https://cli.github.com/manual/installation)

1. gh repo create - follow instruction
2. if you choose not to clone locally then continue the below assuming you are inside the working folder else the repo has been cloned into the current folder.
3. git init
4. git git remote add origin `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>`
5. git branch -M main
6. now local folder and repo are connected and you are ready to go.
7. want to delete the repo? first get admin rights if you don't have it.
8. gh auth refresh -h github.com -s delete_repo
9. gh repo delete `<repo>` --confirm

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to figure out the complete process via the command prompt CLI, here it is:

```
#1 Install GitHub CLI(gh command) on your local PC if it's not done already

winget install --id GitHub.cli


#2 From console go to your root project path:

cd "C:\Users\jctor\<MY_PROJECT_ROOT>"


#3 Check gh command is recognized on your console.

gh --version


#4 Authenticate first to your remote github dashboard via HTTPS token or 
SSH key(follow prompt)

gh auth login


#5 Execute the "gh command" to create a remote repository in your gitHub 
using the local source code and project's name. 
(source=means root path of project's source code, public= visibility of remote) 

gh repo create --source=. --public --description "Kotlin cours "


#6 Push the local commits to the brand new remote repository on your github 
dashBoard

git push --set-upstream origin main
```

Done! your remote git repository is up and running !

Answer (score 0):

[`gh repo create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create), from [gh 2.21.0 (Dec. 2022)](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.21.0) is more precise when it comes to the new repository owner:

> When creating new repos interactively, users are only prompted for a repo name, and it's not immediately clear that names can be prefixed in order to create the repo in an Organization.
>
> ### Proposed solution
>
> If I enter an un-prefixed name, I'd like to be presented with a select prompt containing my personal account name (the default) and all organizations I am a member of:
>
> [image: owner selection -- https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/245879/200487503-cef84b03-964f-4c31-b502-158f16444219.png]