# Does `git push` require the destination repository already exist?

Tags: git

When using `git push`, must the destination repository already exist?

If the destination repository doesn't exist, how can I create it from my local machine?

Comment: You are right, I misread.

Answer (score 3):

The repository must exist. It's an issue of security. A repository must be created by someone with the correct permissions on the server side. Once the repository exists, you will usually have permissions to create new branches within it though.

I know of two ways to set up a repo on a remote machine. The simplest is to SSH in and make either init or clone a repo. If you do not have permission to do this, I'd ask the admin if the machine to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

For most servers or git hostings you must create a repository in advance before pushing. But there are a few clients or servers that can create repository on push.

I've heard that Github Desktop (a client for Github) can create a repository on push though I cannot find it in the docs.

Also if you want to create a repository at Github and don't want to use a web browser you can create a repository [using Github API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35128644/7976758). To simplify things I recommend to use a command line wrapper for the API like [hub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35125094/7976758).

[Gitlab can create a repository on push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49317471/7976758).

Gitlab also has [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project) and a lot of command-line wrappers. [git repo](https://github.com/guyzmo/git-repo) works with Github, Gitlab and Bitbucket.

Comment: I didn't know GitLab let you do that (+1). To be clear though, all of these are examples of special extension scripts that are not part of normal vanilla git.

Comment: Of course. You cannot create a *remote* repository using vanilla git commands. Only local though even this is possible from command line over ssh: `ssh server 'cd /path/to/parent/dir && git init newrepo'`.