# How to push a new local repository in github account from ubuntu terminal?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push a new local "repo" into my GitHub account which doesn't exist with command:

```
git push https://github.com/username/gitinit
```

Getting error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/gitinit/' not found
```

My question is:

Can we create a repo (which doesn't exists in GitHub account) using command prompt Ubuntu?
And if we can then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use the [GitHub API for Repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create) in order to create a new repo from your Ubuntu shell session.

```
POST /user/repos
```

That is ([from this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960#gistcomment-1360110)):

```
curl -u 'YOUR-USER-NAME' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name": "PUT-YOUR-REPO-NAME-HERE"}'
```

You can add different options:

```
{
  "name": "Hello-World",
  "description": "This is your first repository",
  "homepage": "https://github.com",
  "private": false,
  "has_issues": true,
  "has_wiki": true,
  "has_downloads": true
}
```

Then:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/gitinit.git
git push -u origin master
```

You can find more information/alternatives at "[Is it possible to create a remote repo on GitHub from the CLI without opening browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27774123/6309)".