# create a repo git without using github

Tags: git, github

How can I create a repo git and put it on github to go through the github website ?

I generate a reaction project with 'create-react-app' that I want to put on github

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a remote repo on GitHub from the CLI without opening browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423777/is-it-possible-to-create-a-remote-repo-on-github-from-the-cli-without-opening-br)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the handy-dandy Git 'Hub' tool.
https://hub.github.com/ and https://github.com/github/hub

After installing and configuring that Git add-on, from a local repo type:

```sh
$ git create me/my-project
# i.e. $ git create [org]/[repo]
```

To create a private repo:

```
$ git create -p me/my-private-project
```

Comment: i have this error :

"git: 'create' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
 reset"

Comment: If you didn't add the alias yet, try `$ hub create [org]/[repo]`. To create the alias, see the first section on this page: https://hub.github.com/