# Create Github repo and push files ONLY through git

Tags: git, github, repository

Is there a way for Git to create a GitHub repo then push files to its master branch? Thanks!

Comment: See Github's documentation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+create+repository+command+line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git itself won't create a remote GitHub repo.
Only the [GitHub API can do that](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create).

For instance, without having to install any GitHub API wrapper,  use [a command like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42029459/6309) from a git bash:

```
curl -u 'github-username' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"repo-name"}'
```

Then, inside your local repo:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/github-username/repo-name.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Install hub, and then use `hub create`.

It will ask your github username/password, and then will create public repository with your local project's directory name.

https://hub.github.com