# Git Error "fatal: invalid branch name: init.defaultBranch ="

Tags: git, github

I getting this error when ever I do `git clone`

Error :-
`fatal: invalid branch name: init.defaultBranch =`

Tried to reinstall git (latest)

Still same error

OS :- Windows

[image: Git CMD Log]

Comment: If its public repo can you share the link so I can test it?

Comment: @VladimirBozhinovski Its a normal repo. I cant clone any repo at all

Comment: Please share some screenshot, for better debugging purpose

Comment: @VladimirBozhinovski Shared

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It would appear that you have experimented with the [new (2.28) `init.defaultBranch` configuration value](https://github.blog/2020-07-27-highlights-from-git-2-28/).

Assign it a proper value:

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend removing the configuration instead with `git config --unset --global init.defaultBranch` which will allow Git to fall back to its default behavior.

Comment: Good point @ADTC, now you can, as Git comes with the default setting `main` unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 34):

Got it

Enter this in terminal

`git config --global init.defaultBranch master`

Answer (score 9):

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), this should be clearer, as the users are trained to prepare for future change of `init.defaultBranch` configuration variable.

See [commit 675704c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/675704c74dd4476f455bfa91e72eb9e163317c10), [commit cc0f13c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc0f13c57dedaf62c9f852b6bf363aee7e3392f1), [commit cfaff3a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfaff3aac8063ec72f03c6761328c7fa44a15b34), [commit 1296cbe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1296cbe4b4675f429eb20b85bb86ec61546103fb) (11 Dec 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 772bdcd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/772bdcd4296b259d52aafb0badd79872e9db3bb3), 18 Dec 2020)</sup>

> ### [`init`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/675704c74dd4476f455bfa91e72eb9e163317c10): provide useful advice about `init.defaultBranch`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> To give ample warning for users wishing to override Git's the fall-back for an unconfigured `init.defaultBranch` (in case we decide to change it in a future Git version), let's introduce some advice that is shown upon [`git init`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/675704c74dd4476f455bfa91e72eb9e163317c10/Documentation/git-init.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init))</sup> when that value is not set.
>
> Note: two test cases in Git's test suite want to verify that the `stderr` output of `[`git init`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/675704c74dd4476f455bfa91e72eb9e163317c10/Documentation/git-init.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init))</sup>`  is empty.
> It is now necessary to suppress the advice, we now do that via the `init.defaultBranch` setting. While not strictly necessary, we also set this to `false` in `test_create_repo()`.

The advice now is:

> Using '%s' as the name for the initial branch.
>
> This default branch name is subject to change.
> To configure the initial branch name to use in all of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
>
> ```
> git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
> ```
>
> Names commonly chosen instead of '`master`' are '`main`', '`trunk`' and '`development`'.
> The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
>
> ```
> git branch -m <name>
> ```

---

And:

> ### [`init`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1296cbe4b4675f429eb20b85bb86ec61546103fb): document `init.defaultBranch` better
>
> <sup>Initial-patch-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> Our documentation does not mention any future plan to change 'master' to other value. It is a good idea to document this, though.

`git init` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1296cbe4b4675f429eb20b85bb86ec61546103fb/Documentation/git-init.txt#L23-L25):

> An initial branch without any
> commits will be created (see the `--initial-branch` option below
> for its name).

`git init` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1296cbe4b4675f429eb20b85bb86ec61546103fb/Documentation/git-init.txt#L23-L25):

> ### `--initial-branch`
>
> Use the specified name for the initial branch in the newly created
> repository.
> If not specified, fall back to the default name (currently
> `master`, but this is subject to change in the future; the name can be
> customized via the `init.defaultBranch` configuration variable).

---

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), error messages given when working on an unborn branch that is checked out in another worktree have been improved.

See [commit 3521c63](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3521c6321350cf1432f4772efa09db8bec0aa331), [commit a675ad1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a675ad1708383f47883d0bb0b2dada827a295acd), [commit 7a6ccdf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a6ccdfb4eeb9d55893eae9b2c7e573b92f3d01d), [commit d7f4ca6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7f4ca61b51da5655df09277309380794ba1bd19), [commit 2e8af49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e8af499ff6e166a5f54f18cf3d1fa8f5d9bde38) (27 Mar 2023) by [Rubén Justo (`rjusto`)](https://github.com/rjusto).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d3f2e4a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3f2e4ab13f54ec3de1ac752e41d30847974c140), 15 May 2023)</sup>

> ### [`branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a675ad1708383f47883d0bb0b2dada827a295acd): rename orphan branches in any worktree
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Rubén Justo</sup>

> In [cfaff3a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfaff3aac8063ec72f03c6761328c7fa44a15b34) ("branch -m: allow renaming a yet-unborn branch", 2020-12-13, Git v2.30.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/772bdcd4296b259d52aafb0badd79872e9db3bb3)) we added support for renaming an orphan branch when that branch is checked out in the current worktree.
>
> Let's also allow renaming an orphan branch checked out in a worktree different than the current one.

Answer (score 2):

I was having same error during react App Deployment on Git-hub pages

tried code :
`git config ---global init.defaultBranch master`

Answer (score 2):

You can set it to a value as mentioned in @CodeCaster's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64350235/888621).

But It would make life easier is you just unset that value so that the default configured one from the remote will be chosen.

You can either use the follwoing command:

```bash
git config --unset --global init.defaultBranch
```

Or remove the corresponding config line from `~/.gitconfig` file.