# Github "Problems parsing JSON", Creating Repository from console on Windows 10

Tags: github, curl, windows-10

I was trying to create a new Repository from CMD on `Windows 10 Pro`, following this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325316

My First Try

```
C:\Users\joseluisbz>curl -u joseluisbz https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"BasicOperations"}'
Enter host password for user 'joseluisbz':                                                                                       
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",                                                                                               
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user"
}
```

The second try

```
C:\Users\joseluisbz>curl -u joseluisbz https://api.github.com/user/repos -d \'{"name":"BasicOperations"}\'
Enter host password for user 'joseluisbz':                                                                                        
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",                                                                                           
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user"
}
C:\Users\joseluisbz>
```

From `macOS` works perfectly.

```
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air Java % curl -u joseluisbz https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"BasicOperations"}'
Enter host password for user 'joseluisbz':
{
  "id": 293512428,
  "node_id": "I CHANGED THIS HASH",
  "name": "BasicOperations",
  "full_name": "joseluisbz/BasicOperations",
  "private": false,
  "owner": {
    "login": "joseluisbz",
    "id": 16026347,
    "node_id": "I CHANGED THIS HASH",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/16026347?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/joseluisbz",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "html_url": "https://github.com/joseluisbz/BasicOperations",
  "description": null,
  "fork": false,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations",
  "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/forks",
  "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/keys{/key_id}",
  "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/collaborators{/collaborator}",
  "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/teams",
  "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/hooks",
  "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/issues/events{/number}",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/events",
  "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/assignees{/user}",
  "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/branches{/branch}",
  "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/tags",
  "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/git/blobs{/sha}",
  "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/git/tags{/sha}",
  "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/git/refs{/sha}",
  "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/git/trees{/sha}",
  "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/statuses/{sha}",
  "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/languages",
  "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/stargazers",
  "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/contributors",
  "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/subscribers",
  "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/subscription",
  "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/commits{/sha}",
  "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/git/commits{/sha}",
  "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/comments{/number}",
  "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/issues/comments{/number}",
  "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/contents/{+path}",
  "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/compare/{base}...{head}",
  "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/merges",
  "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/{archive_format}{/ref}",
  "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/downloads",
  "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/issues{/number}",
  "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/pulls{/number}",
  "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/milestones{/number}",
  "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
  "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/labels{/name}",
  "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/releases{/id}",
  "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations/deployments",
  "created_at": "2020-09-07T11:45:04Z",
  "updated_at": "2020-09-07T11:45:04Z",
  "pushed_at": "2020-09-07T11:45:06Z",
  "git_url": "git://github.com/joseluisbz/BasicOperations.git",
  "ssh_url": "git@github.com:joseluisbz/BasicOperations.git",
  "clone_url": "https://github.com/joseluisbz/BasicOperations.git",
  "svn_url": "https://github.com/joseluisbz/BasicOperations",
  "homepage": null,
  "size": 0,
  "stargazers_count": 0,
  "watchers_count": 0,
  "language": null,
  "has_issues": true,
  "has_projects": true,
  "has_downloads": true,
  "has_wiki": true,
  "has_pages": false,
  "forks_count": 0,
  "mirror_url": null,
  "archived": false,
  "disabled": false,
  "open_issues_count": 0,
  "license": null,
  "forks": 0,
  "open_issues": 0,
  "watchers": 0,
  "default_branch": "master",
  "permissions": {
    "admin": true,
    "push": true,
    "pull": true
  },
  "allow_squash_merge": true,
  "allow_merge_commit": true,
  "allow_rebase_merge": true,
  "delete_branch_on_merge": false,
  "network_count": 0,
  "subscribers_count": 1
}
joseluisbz@Joses-MacBook-Air Java %
```

EDIT 1:

```
C:\Users\joseluisbz>curl --version
curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL
Release-Date: 2017-11-14, security patched: 2019-11-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL

C:\Users\joseluisbz>
```

I was testing too with https://curl.haxx.se/windows/dl-7.72.0_4/curl-7.72.0_4-win64-mingw.zip with the same problems

```
D:\Programs\curl-7.72.0-win64-mingw\bin
λ curl.exe --version
curl 7.72.0 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.72.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1g (Schannel) zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.4.5 WinIDN libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.41.0
Release-Date: 2020-08-19
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile MultiSSL NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI TLS-SRP Unicode UnixSockets brotli libz zstd

D:\Programs\curl-7.72.0-win64-mingw\bin
```

**What would be the problem?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working changing the Trailing BackSlash

```
curl -u joseluisbz https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "{\"name\":\"BasicOperations3\"}"
```

Example

```
i:\joseluisbz\NetBeansProjects\BasicOperations (master -> origin)
λ curl -u joseluisbz https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "{\"name\":\"BasicOperations3\"}"
Enter host password for user 'joseluisbz':
{
  "id": 293578020,
  "node_id": "CHANCED HASH",
  "name": "BasicOperations3",
  "full_name": "joseluisbz/BasicOperations3",
  "private": false,
  "owner": {
    "login": "joseluisbz",
    "id": 16026347,
    "node_id": "CHANCED HASH",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/16026347?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/joseluisbz",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joseluisbz/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "html_url": "https://github.com/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3",
  "description": null,
  "fork": false,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3",
  "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/forks",
  "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/keys{/key_id}",
  "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/collaborators{/collaborator}",
  "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/teams",
  "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/hooks",
  "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/issues/events{/number}",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/events",
  "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/assignees{/user}",
  "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/branches{/branch}",
  "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/tags",
  "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/git/blobs{/sha}",
  "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/git/tags{/sha}",
  "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/git/refs{/sha}",
  "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/git/trees{/sha}",
  "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/statuses/{sha}",
  "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/languages",
  "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/stargazers",
  "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/contributors",
  "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/subscribers",
  "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/subscription",
  "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/commits{/sha}",
  "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/git/commits{/sha}",
  "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/comments{/number}",
  "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/issues/comments{/number}",
  "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/contents/{+path}",
  "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/compare/{base}...{head}",
  "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/merges",
  "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/{archive_format}{/ref}",
  "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/downloads",
  "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/issues{/number}",
  "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/pulls{/number}",
  "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/milestones{/number}",
  "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
  "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/labels{/name}",
  "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/releases{/id}",
  "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3/deployments",
  "created_at": "2020-09-07T16:26:45Z",
  "updated_at": "2020-09-07T16:26:45Z",
  "pushed_at": "2020-09-07T16:26:46Z",
  "git_url": "git://github.com/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3.git",
  "ssh_url": "git@github.com:joseluisbz/BasicOperations3.git",
  "clone_url": "https://github.com/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3.git",
  "svn_url": "https://github.com/joseluisbz/BasicOperations3",
  "homepage": null,
  "size": 0,
  "stargazers_count": 0,
  "watchers_count": 0,
  "language": null,
  "has_issues": true,
  "has_projects": true,
  "has_downloads": true,
  "has_wiki": true,
  "has_pages": false,
  "forks_count": 0,
  "mirror_url": null,
  "archived": false,
  "disabled": false,
  "open_issues_count": 0,
  "license": null,
  "forks": 0,
  "open_issues": 0,
  "watchers": 0,
  "default_branch": "master",
  "permissions": {
    "admin": true,
    "push": true,
    "pull": true
  },
  "allow_squash_merge": true,
  "allow_merge_commit": true,
  "allow_rebase_merge": true,
  "delete_branch_on_merge": false,
  "network_count": 0,
  "subscribers_count": 1
}

i:\joseluisbz\NetBeansProjects\BasicOperations (master -> origin)
```

Comment: WINDOWS USERS: This is the answer. Many other forums have this question answered with quote-escaping that will _not_ work on Windows.